# OAuth Authentication error

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth, request, quickbooks

I am trying to use the QuickBooks REST API by carrying out a test API call.  I am adding my own application token and consumer token, however receiving the following error:

```
{
    "Fault": {
        "Error": [
            {
                "Message": "message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401",
                "code": "3200"
            }
        ],
        "type": "AUTHENTICATION"
    },
    "requestId": "999c6895a5cf42a1aeaacc43bf600cca",
    "time": "2015-06-08T19:57:10.669Z"
}
```

The OAuth string is in the following format: `Authorization : OAuth oauth_token="************",oauth_nonce="39316429-ad1d-4aa2-9ba7-d59e380878b3",oauth_consumer_key="************",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1433794011",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="KIC7BXeSXVqw6C%2Fcgcb0Dlq2R40%3D"`

I am substituting the "oauth_token" and "oauth_consumer_key" values with the **App Token** and **OAuth Consumer Key** values from the QuickBooks developer section, as shown below:

[image]

From what I have looked up online, the key values are expired, but that does not seem likely as I am simply copy-pasting them from that page on QuickBooks developers section.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried loading values from this page, after submitting my app token, however I am receiving the same exact error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am substituting the "oauth_token" ... with the App Token

This is incorrect. This isn't how OAuth works.

You need to go through the OAuth connection process (e.g. click the "Connect to QuickBooks" button) to get your OAuth token.

The `App Token` is *not* the same thing as the `OAuth token`. They are two totally independent separate values.

If you post what programming language you're using, you'll probably get more details relevant to what you're actually building in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I realised this after I posted, so tried generating the values from the page as demonstrated in my new updated screenshot.  However, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @user2641077  Post your HTTP request and HTTP response. Post the code you're using to generate the OAuth headers. Post the URL you're hitting.